# android udp socket stops sending/recieving if activity goes in background

Tags: android, udp, background-process

I have two separte threads for sending and recieving udp packets (audio stream) and everything works perfectly as long as I am on the same screen. But I have a button on my screen that opens up another screen. When I go to that screen I start receiving garbage in my speaker from both phones. Does any one know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and work wth your sockets inside these.